# If $p$ is prime, then $x^p − 2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p^k}$ has a solution for $k \ge 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, hensels-lemma

> If $p$ is prime, then $x^p − 2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p^k}$ has a solution for $k \ge 2$.

I'm supposed to either prove or disprove the statement above using Hensel's Lemma.

So far what I have is assuming $r$ is a solution to $x^p − 2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p^{k-1}}$. I can show that $f'(r) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ since $f'(r) = p(r^{p-1})$.

I think the next step should be showing that $f(r)\not\equiv0\pmod{p^k}$ which would show that there are no solutions but I don't know how to go about doing this without any way to properly represent $r$.

Comment: Have you looked at any examples?

Comment: I have but the only ones I can find are for solutions to equations where all the numbers are explicitly stated other than x, not with p and k as variables still

Comment: The very first example would be $x^2\equiv 2 \pmod 4$.  Are there any solutions to that?  If you want to exclude $p=2$ then the first example is $x^3\equiv 2 \pmod 9$.  Are there any solutions to that?

Comment: Oh that's what you meant, yeah I checked and saw that it wasn't true for a couple but the question asks me to use Hensel's lemma so I assume they don't want me to  just provide a counterexample

Comment: You asked "prove or disprove" the claim.  A single counterexample disproves a claim.

Comment: Yeah I know this disproves it, but just disproving it isn't the question I'm asking. I'm asking how I could disprove it specifically using Hensel's lemma

Answer (score 2):

The claim is true very, very rarely (at least for "small" $p$).  Even for $k=2$.  In fact, the challenge here is to find a single prime $p$ for which the claim holds.  Indeed, only two are known.

To see this, note that the unique solution to $x^p\equiv 2\pmod p$ is $x\equiv 2 \pmod p$.

If we try to lift this to a solution $\pmod {p^2}$  we write $x\equiv 2 +tp\pmod {p^2}$ and try to solve for $t$.  We get $$x^{p}\equiv (2+tp)^{p}\equiv 2^{p}\pmod {p^2}$$

Note that this does not depend on $t$.

Thus we want a prime $p$ such that $$2^{p}\equiv 2 \pmod {p^2}$$

Such primes are known as [Weiferich primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime) and they are staggeringly rare for small numbers.  Indeed, only two examples are known, namely $1093$ and $3511$.  And people have searched rather a lot.  Up to about $5\times 10^{17}$ according to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001220).